# Visual Studio 2015 hangs when create/open a Cordova project

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I used Visual Studio 2015 to develop mobile app with Cordova. Before I upgraded to Windows10, I was using Windows 7 and it worked perfectly fine. After I've upgraded to Windows10, whenever I open a Cordova project or create a Cordova project the Visual Studio hangs (not responding).

I have tried to reinstall the Visual Studio but it still hangs.

Anyone has faced this problem before?

Thanks

Comment: I would try to start Visual Studio with logging enabled from the command line: devenv.exe /Log c:\pathtolog\vslog.log

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx

Comment: I have the same problem on 2 laptops. One win10 upgraded from win81pro. Had VS2013update4 with cordova-tools. Uninstalled cordova tools, installed VS2013update5. Now can't run cordova tools. Upgraded to win10. Installed VS2015 - system hangs when creating blank cordova project. Files for a project are created in the folder. But when manually try to add project to solution, it hangs.

Comment: Here's tail of the log file http://pastebin.com/NnRAHUWZ (total file 300kb)

Comment: Same exact issue.  Windows 10 + VS 2015 + Creating New Tools for Apache Cordova (aka "TAC") project. 

I tried uninstalling + reinstalling both VS 2015 completely, as well as just the TAC feature.  I rebooted, and have tried all the traditional troubleshooting techniques.

Also, it appears it will NOT open an existing TAC program as well.

Also, even without creating a new Cordova project, if I go under tools->options->TAC, I get an error saying "an error occurred loading this property page".  But this started showing up after I made a few attempts to try to fix/reinstall TAC.

Comment: Doesn't look like my log file, or the one @DimitryK posted has any indication of any error.

Comment: actually at first I was able to open my Cordova project, but when I build it it failed with few errors like "cmd failed with error code 1 , failed with error code 2, couldnt create java virtual machine". I tried installing newer java jdk and configuring some path and after that my cordova project wont open anymore :(

Answer (score 18):

Here is the solution for this problem in VS 2015. This issue if you have Windows 10 and latest updates in VS 2015 including latest type script installation.

1) Open command prompt as administrator.

2) Navigate to the following folder path:

```
cd "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache"
```

3) write the following command to find out **vs_edition.exe** file:

```
dir vs*exe /s /b
```

4) copy the full path that contains your vs edition exe from the screen.

5) write the following command:

```
"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{GUID}\vs_enterprise.exe" /modify /installselectableitems Javascript
```

6) VS installer will start, click on modify and then update. no need to change any features selection.

7) Wait until the installer finishes.

8) From the command prompt, navigate to the following folder:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE

9) Run the following commands:

```
devenv /updateconfiguration

devenv /clearcache
```

Below screenshot shows the full commands set.

[image]

Now, you will be able to open VS 2015 and create cordova apps.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue, and the solution is mentioned in the following [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0e5115ca-83a7-4294-8740-289b3f453fca/rtm-known-issue-package-load-failure-when-creating-a-windows-app-project-with-javascript-or-hang?forum=Win10SDKToolsIssues).

I still had few more issues with the Blank Cordova Project which would simply not build once the hanging issue was fixed. I'll share my experience here to help others.

After recovering from the VS.Net2015 hanging I was still getting

`"Error MSB3073 The command "platforms\android\cordova\clean.bat" exited with code 1.   BlankCordovaApp7    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets   354`"

I tried reinstalling the Android Studio again and found that it was not working, and the issue was: I had installed a 32 bit Java SDK on 64Bit OS. After In installed the 64Bit JDK and correcting the Path variable to point to this directory, I was able to start the Android Studio.

Now my Blank Cordova project was still not compiling with an error

```
'MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,   BlankCordovaApp7    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets   287
```

This was an interesting one, looks like its an issue with MySQL, in the PATH variable there were some & within the path. I used "" to surround those path

Now its compiling and also able to start the Ripple.

Hope it helps someone as it took me more than 2 weeks to fix.

Regards
Kiran

Comment: In my case, I was running VS 2015, Apache Cordova project happily since July 20th.  My Surface upgraded to Windows 10, and everything still worked, but at various times, various errors were occurring with various emulators. Then, yesterday, VS2015 suggested that I upgrade to Cordova tools update 1.  My eyes lit up at the prospect of bugs being fixed.  Instead, I lost a whole day and gained a lot of stress because of this problem.  It was fixed by the link in the first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Today , solved for me with Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova **Update 2** for VS2015 Enterprise & Windows 8.1. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some updates for Visual Studio 2015. I reinstalled it and it is working now.

Here is what I did:

1. Uninstall the Visual Studio 2015 using the installer (vs-community.exe) from https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx
2. Install Visual Studio 2015 using the same installer(vs-community.exe) and choose **Typical Installation**
3. After the installation is done, run the installer (vs-community.exe) again and choose **Custom Installation** and choose to install **Apache Cordova**
4. Then I am able to open and build Cordova project

Not sure if this helps.

Comment: What's the version of your Visual Studio? I mean detailed version of the build.

Comment: I tried reinstalling VS2015 with custom installation and selecting Apache Cordova tools, and it kinda improved things - After that reinstallation I was able to  open Cordova projects, but didn't have new Cordova project template, neither was able to run Ripple simulator. When I tried custom install and uninstalled/ reinstalled the Cordova Tools, I got back to the original hanging problem. What helped was this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0e5115ca-83a7-4294-8740-289b3f453fca/rtm-known-issue-package-load-failure-when-creating-a-windows-app-project-with-javascript-or-hang

Comment: I also had to end up removing/uninstalling Visual Studio all together.  Reboot, and re-install. Probably was faster then digging into finding the actual failure point.  I ended up re-installing Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 FIRST, and then added Visual Studio 2015.  I think 2013 Update 5 broke TAC for VS 2015. Not sure though.

Comment: "some updates for Visual Studio 2015". What does it means. Do you get update in windows update ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case with VS2015, the problem was about missing SDK build tools for Android. The lack of information is due to the fact that Visual Studio does not show all the build information by default. Once more information is shown, we could see issues with third party dependency issues like Android build tool. There are a couple of ways to get more information during a build.

MSBuild build output verbosity
Dependency checker on the Cordova    tools

Both of these are available from the tools menu. For more information see this post:

http://www.ozkary.com/2016/01/visual-studio-2015-apache-cordova.html

hope it helps.