# Visual Studio 2015 hangs when create new cordova project

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, visual-studio-cordova

I used Visual Studio 2015 enterprise & windows 10 (64bit) , when i create new cordova project , the Visual Studio 2015 hangs

I follow this case ([enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31771585/visual-studio-2015-hangs-when-create-open-a-cordova-project)) solution , but still can't resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to repair Visual Studio by:

- Goto Control Panel
- Open Add/Remove Programs
- Locate/Click "Microsoft Visual Studio  2015"
- Click on "Change"
- Click on "Repair"

Comment: I tried remove windows 10 UWP Core and reinstall it , resolve this issue .